# serverless .yml environment variable issues

Tags: aws-lambda, environment-variables, serverless

I am on [this](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/add-a-create-note-api.html) page of a serverless with Lambdas and Dynamo DB exercise.

I am on the " Add a Create Note API" section and am having trouble with testing the API
the command:

```
serverless invoke local --function create --path mocks/create-event.json
```

produces this error

```
Serverless: DOTENV: Loading environment variables from .env:
Serverless:      - tableName
Serverless: Bundling with Webpack...
error is : ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found
    at Request.extractError (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at Request.emit (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at callNextListener (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/dannybyrne/notes-app-api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:307:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  message: 'Requested resource not found',
  code: 'ResourceNotFoundException',
  time: 2019-12-10T18:33:00.494Z,
  requestId: '4D2O3VOI437AE9MTH1M4UPGDUVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 28.999931507407407
}
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    },
    "body": "{\"status\":false}"
}
```

I have edited the .env file to have

```
tableName='notes'
```

though in the .yml file is says

```
# These environment variables are made available to our functions
  # under process.env.
  environment:
    tableName: notes
```

I'm assuming this means that in the create.js file, under the params object

```
TableName: process.env.tableName,
```

In the instructions it says
" We read the name of our DynamoDB table from the environment variable using  `process.env.tableName` . We’ll be setting this in our  `serverless.yml`  below. We do this so we won’t have to hardcode it in every function."

Does this mean that I don't have to set it in the .env file that is included?  when I rename this file to not be included in the build it also throws an error asking for it. When I define tableName in .env and set it to 'notes', as is defined in the .yml file and is the name of the dynamoDB table, it throws the above error.

I'm basically trying to figure out hoew .yml pull from .env (or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you define the variable under the provider it'll be available to all the functions.

Comment: How are you using the .env file. Can you explain

Comment: i'm really trying to figure that out myself.  the point of the .env file is to keep params hidden, why are we defining .env variables in the .yml file in the first place?

Comment: you are using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dotenv-plugin` right. ok, i am using the `.env` method at the moment. you can do it either way. if you do it in `.env` files, you don't need to include it under the `provider`. i think the of benefit using `.env` files is, you can include the environment specific `.env` file from S3 during the deployment process.